# Is "against" used correctly in this context?

Tags: word-usage

> She has the right to know why her husband died; the company should give her that information.
>
> Does she have such right **against** the the company?
>
> Does such right hold **against** the company?
>
> Yes, in such cases, the employees' family has the right, **against** the employers, to be informed of the cause of death.

So, the right is *to* something, and *against* someone or some organization. Is that correct?

Comment: Could you please provide more context?  Is this something you made up yourself, or something you read in an (English-language) text?

Answer (score 1):

Such forms as:

> - A has a right to XYZ against B.
> - A's rights will hold against B.
> - A has a riht to damages as against B, but not as against C.

are very common in English-language legal writing. This use of "against" implies that A may be involved in a lawsuit against B, and that the specified right(s) will be upheld in the course of such a suit, if it occurs. A right "against B" is a right that will be enforced when B is the opposition.

However the phrase "right against" is also used, although less frequently, to describe a violation of rights.

> - A has a right to be secure against an unreasonable search.
> - B has a right against an invasion of privacy in such a case.